# c# equivalent of php's ini_set('memory_limit','400M');

Tags: c#, php, asp.net-mvc

Just curious, does anyone know of a similar way to increase the memory limit of a web-page.

This is how I did it in php:

```
ini_set('memory_limit','120M');
```

Is there a way to achieve the same in c# MVC? I am using internet explorer as my browser.

Comment: What is connection between internet explorer and asp.net? You want to limit memory that used for one page generation? or what?

Comment: if you want to limit maximum memory that used asp.net for one page, then you can't do it. as asp.net is processing all pages in the same process, and you can limit memory limit for the whole process, but not for specific page.

Comment: There is no direct equivalent for this setting as asp.net is not limited in memory usage.  Clarify the context as there might be other methods you can employ.

Comment: Yes. I want to increase the amount of memory a page can use. I used this php code on a page that was pulling in large amounts of data from a database. This caused the page to be very slow. Adding in that php code above allowed the page to run more smoothly.

Comment: @Sunday1290 As you are presumably converting `PHP` code to `.NET` - Do the conversion first before attempting to optimise.  This appears to be a specific fix for a specific issue experienced in `PHP`. It is likely that this issue may never appear in `.NET`.

Answer (score 0):

As I am aware the answer is no, you can not change the memory limit on runtime. 
But you can change it from IIS settings. I assume that you are familiar with [processModel Element](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7w2sway1%28v=VS.100%29.aspx). There you can change the `memoryLimit` option. The value is a percentage of the maximum available memory of the server.

Beware that prior .Net 4 the memory limit of .NET object was 2GB. To exceed that limit you have to enable `gcAllowVeryLargeObjects` in `autoConfig` file. Have in mind that this feature works only in 64bit servers.